# Why results of assign and return is different?

Tags: php

Result of assign of variable is differrent from return of a function:

```
function test() {
return !true
    or !true
    or !count(4)
    or (
        new stdClass() and true
    );
}

$result = !true
        or !true
        or !count(4)
        or (
            new stdClass() and true
        );

echo (int)$result . PHP_EOL; // 0

echo (int)test() . PHP_EOL; // 1
```

Comment: My assumption would be, that in function return counts all parts of boolean expression and in assigment part without round brackets only first `!true` is assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the **[Operator Precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)**.

**Assignment operation** has higher Precedence than `and` / `or`.

First one is equal to:

```
function test() {
return (!true
    or !true
    or !count(4)
    or (
        new stdClass() and true
    ));
}
```

while second one is equal to:

```
($result = !true)
        or !true
        or !count(4)
        or (
            new stdClass() and true
        );
```

Using `&&`/`||` instead of `and`/`or`, then the result will be same.